# Cannot initialize the indexer process in Magento 1.6

Tags: magento

I have spent 3 hours now trying to resolve this error when trying to re-index my catalog in the Admin.

I do not want Magento to manage my inventory, so I set it to No in the Inventory area of the admin.  When I go to re-index the site, I get the error "Cannot initialize the indexer process.”

I have searched here and on Google, and the 2 or 3 mentions of it, those solutions do not work for me.  And when I try to change back to have Magento manage inventory, since I cannot get it to re-index, all of my products just disappear from the public side.

The only way to get my products back is to re-import the database and start over.  But then, when you try to add a product to your cart, since I do not keep my own inventory, the user gets an inventory error.

Has anyone seen this issue with 1.6 and found a solution?

Comment: Oh, the correct folders in /var/ are writeable, and I have already tried deleting the files within those folders and re-indexing.  Same issue occurs.

Comment: have you tried to grep the error message from codebase and see on what error condition it triggers?

Comment: Sorry, Anton, I have no idea what that means :-(

Comment: I just tried installing another fresh copy of Magento on a completely different domain, and I get the same error based on these conditions.  Completelt new install, different domain, inventory management turned off, error shows up...

Comment: have you verified that your server meets the magento requirements and your db has innodb engine

Comment: i am also facing the same issue, when i try to reindex from admin panel, it outputs this error above.
i have DB engine as innodb and i also deleted everything in var but still facing this error

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem, after trying almost all the solutions listed on forums with no results.

What i did is, **changed my DB user and assigned him all the rights.** Before that the user of my DB didn't have all the rights.

**Note:**

**This may not be the case with everyone but still it is a solution for me.**